# How do I overwrite and rewrite text in Python Turtle?

Tags: python, windows, turtle-graphics

The problem is in the `#num` comment changes, section.  It is supposed to draw a green box around the number, then write a new one in it's place.  First, I tested `#AP` and it worked perfectly.  So I added `#HP` but for some reason it didn't work and `#AP` stopped as well.  I got no error messages, and I looked though it but I couldn't see a problem.

```
import turtle
import winsound
import os
import time
#screen
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor("green")
wn.title("game")
hp=100
ap=10

def song1():
    winsound.PlaySound("sound1", winsound.SND_FILENAME)


#menu
time.sleep(2)
men_pen = turtle.Turtle()
men_pen.speed(0)
men_pen.color("black")
men_pen.penup()
men_pen.setposition(-1000,-200)
men_pen.pensize(4)
men_pen.pendown()
men_pen.fd(2500)

#menu text
men_pen.penup()
men_pen.setposition(-625,-265)
men_pen.pendown()
men_pen.write("HP=",True,font=('terminal',18, 'bold'))
men_pen.penup()
men_pen.setposition(-560,-265)
men_pen.pendown()
men_pen.write(hp ,font=('terminal',18,'bold'))
men_pen.penup()
men_pen.setposition(-625,-312)
men_pen.pendown()
men_pen.write("AP=",True,font=('terminal',18,'bold'))
men_pen.penup()
men_pen.setposition(-560,-312)
men_pen.write(ap ,font=('terminal',18,'bold'))
men_pen.penup()
men_pen.setposition(-499,-240)
men_pen.pendown()
men_pen.write("William" ,True,font=('terminal',20,'bold'))

#num changers
#AP
ap1= turtle.Turtle()
ap1.speed(0)
ap1.penup()
ap1.color("green")
ap1.penup()
ap1.setposition(-559,-311)
ap1.pendown()
def changeap():
    ap1.down()
    ap1.begin_fill()
    for i in range(4):
        ap1.penup()
        ap1.fd(36)
        ap1.left(90)
    ap1.color("green")
    ap1.end_fill()
    ap1.pendown()
    men_pen.penup()
    men_pen.setposition(-560,-312)

    men_pen.write(ap ,font=('terminal',18,'bold'))
    men_pen.penup()

#HP
hp2=turtle.Turtle()
hp2.speed(0)
hp2.penup()
hp2.color("green")
hp2.setposition(-561,-314)
hp2.pendown()

def changehp():
    hp2.down()
    hp2.begin_fill()
    for i in range(4):
        hp2.fd(50)
        hp2.left(90)
    hp2.color("green")
    hp2.end_fill()
    hp2.pendown()
    men_pen.penup()
    men_pen.setposition(-560,-312)
    men_pen.pendown()
    men_pen.write(ap , font=('Terminal',18,'bold'))




hp = 20
ap = 1000
time.sleep(5)
changeap()
time.sleep(5)
changehp()
```

Comment: Please consider providing a [mcve]. And, please provide a more descriptive title. Please [edit] your question.

Comment: "it didn't work" is not specific enough. Please describe the issue as precisely as possible.

Answer (score 1):

There's a simpler way to go about this.  Rather than overwrite the text with a background-colored rectangle, we can use the `.clear()` (or `.undo()`) method of turtle to remove the text for us before we rewrite it anew:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
import time

FONT = ('terminal', 18, 'bold')

def changeap():
    ap_pen.clear()
    ap_pen.write(ap, font=FONT)

def changehp():
    hp_pen.clear()
    hp_pen.write(hp, font=FONT)

# screen
screen = Screen()
screen.setup(1300, 650)
screen.bgcolor("green")
screen.title("game")

hp = 100
ap = 10

# menu
men_pen = Turtle(visible=False)
men_pen.speed('fastest')
men_pen.pensize(4)

men_pen.penup()
men_pen.setposition(-650, -200)
men_pen.pendown()
men_pen.fd(1300)

# num changers
# AP
ap_pen = Turtle(visible=False)
ap_pen.speed('fastest')
ap_pen.penup()
ap_pen.setposition(-560, -312)

# HP
hp_pen = Turtle(visible=False)
hp_pen.speed('fastest')
hp_pen.penup()
hp_pen.setposition(-560, -265)

# menu text
men_pen.penup()
men_pen.setposition(-625, -265)
men_pen.write("HP=", True, font=FONT)

hp_pen.write(hp, font=FONT)

men_pen.setposition(-625, -312)
men_pen.write("AP=", True, font=FONT)

ap_pen.write(ap, font=FONT)

men_pen.setposition(-499, -240)
men_pen.write("William", True, font=FONT)

hp = 20
ap = 1000

time.sleep(5)
changeap()
time.sleep(5)
changehp()

screen.mainloop()
```